# add_filter priorities not working in correct order (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, add-filter

My Wordpress filters seem to be executing in the wrong order.

I've added filters in this way:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'display_a_single_property', 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'the_title', 'change_the_page_title', 11, 2 );
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'change_the_meta_title', 100, 1 );
```

Strangely the order of callback execution is:

- `change_the_meta_title()`
- `display_a_single_property()`
- `change_the_page_title()`

According to the documentation for `add_filter()` the lower the priority numeric, the earlier the execution. However this isn't happening here. Could it be a theme or plugin issue? I'm using *Yoast SEO plugin* and *Colormag* theme.

Comment: I backed up my Wordpress site and temporarily disabled the Yoast SEO plugin. The order of the callbacks is still wrong.

Comment: What are you trying to do that requires these hooks to execute in that specific order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Priorities only order callbacks within each action hook / filter. They don't order the hooks themselves (which always run in the same order).

For example, [`'wp_title'`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_title) **always** runs before [`'the_content'`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content), which in turn **always** runs before [`'the_title'`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_title).

The only time priorities come into effect is if you have multiple callbacks added to the same hook (for example, two different callbacks defined for `'the_content'`).

Comment: Thanks rnevius. That helps a lot. It didn't say that in the documentation, although I am probably learning Wordpress back to front! This gives me a huge clue that I need to understand the high level structure of Wordpress' inner workings before venturing further on. More wisdom and knowledge needed :-)

Comment: You're welcome @MikeX . It actually does say it [in the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action)...but it is easy to gloss over: *`$priority` : Used to specify the order in which the functions **associated with a particular action** are executed.*